# Rails 3 forms and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I'm coming from Asp.Net MVC world and I'm confused how to approach Rails 3 forms from model perspective.
In Asp.Net MVC it is a bad practice to bind to business model forms in templates. The proper approach is to create a class for each form, create properties which are only needed in form and attach validation attributes to them. Then in code check for ModelState.IsValid and assign values from form model to business model. This leads to separation of concepts and also prevents properties hijacking (when hackers might post additional values together with proper values and change business model properties in his cruel way).

From all tutorials and books I've read there is no seperation of this concept in Rails world - you put validation in your business model and you bind your model to the form in the template.

Is it the right approach in Rails 3 and I should follow it? Or I should follow Asp .Net MVC approach and create a separate model with validation just for forms?

Answer (score 0):

In rails, updates of models generally happen via [mass-assignment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes).  For example, a form posts a ton of attributes to your update action, your update action calls:

```
Model.update_attributes(params[:model])
```

and all the values in the passed hash are updated on the model.  The problem then is what happens if a hacker adds

```
params[:model][:users_attributes][:email] = 'hacker@example.com'`
```

and updates the model's associated user's email address?

In Asp.Net MVC it seems like you simply don't allow this in the form template and the value can never get to your models, but in rails this is not the way things are done (correct me if I am misunderstanding Asp.Net MVC).  In Rails, everything in a model (by default) can be mass-assigned, and so your fear is warranted.

In the link I supplied, you can see "For a normal user account, for example, you only want login and password to be editable by a user. It should not be possible to change the status attribute through mass assignment."

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login, :password
end
```

This means any other properties must be set manually and the object saved, thus preventing the same type of property-hijacking that Asp.Net's form templates protect against. In Rails, anything that should be mass-assignable should be in your `attr_accessible` and then ActiveRecord is the gatekeeper. No matter how your forms are written or what a hacker does to their HTML, those attributes can only be updated explicitly by your code, not by Rails' behind-the-scenes stuff.